# Remote port forwarding inside Docker containers

Tags: ssh, docker, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to setup a docker container that I use to bypass firewalls/NAT's to allow SSH access to the computers behind these routing barriers.  In essence, I have an SSH service listening inside of a docker container, that my other computers connect to, opening a reverse-SSH port forwarding, and then if I want to connect to a computer behind a firewall, I instead connect to my dockerized proxy server on the reverse port.  Example:

Firewalled computer "Bob" connects to proxy server:

```
ssh -R 2024:localhost:22 -N remote.server
```

Next, I connect to the remote server on port `2024` so as to follow the tunnel back down and connect to `localhost:22` on bob:

```
ssh -p 2024 remote.server
```

This all works great when it's not dockerized, however when I tried to move this to a dockerized service, I found that my `sshd` server within the docker container stubbornly refuses to open remote port forwards.  Connecting with `ssh -vvv` in the first step above gives:

```
...
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Server has disabled port forwarding.
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug1: remote forward failure for: listen 2024, connect localhost:22
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 2024
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

Which sounds a lot like my `sshd` isn't setup to allow remote port forwarding.  However, my `sshd_config` seems to think it is:

```
# tail /etc/ssh/sshd_config -n 5
GatewayPorts yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
AllowStreamLocalForwarding yes
PermitTunnel yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation no
```

Indeed, running with `ssh -ddd` inside the docker container, then connecting with the line above shows first:

```
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:91 setting GatewayPorts yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:92 setting AllowTcpForwarding yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:93 setting AllowStreamLocalForwarding yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:94 setting PermitTunnel yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:95 setting UsePrivilegeSeparation no
```

Followed by:

```
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype tcpip-forward want_reply 1
debug1: server_input_global_request: tcpip-forward listen localhost port 2024
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

So clearly my configuration is being set correctly, but it seems that the client still thinks the server cannot do port forwarding.  How can I convince the openssh server to perform remote forwarding?  What could cause this failure?

The client is running `OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4`, the server is running `OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4`, the docker version is `17.09.1-ce` on `Amazon Linux 2017.09`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha!  I figured it out.  This was because `docker` was creating an `ipv6` internal network for my containers, and my kernel did not have `ipv6` forwarding enabled.  So when running `sshd` outside of the container, it would work over `ipv4`, but when running `sshd` inside of the container on the docker bridge network, it would listen on `ipv6` and be unable to open port forwards.

Once I enabled `ipv6` forwarding, (adding `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and rebooting) everything starting working just fine.

Comment: Returning to this a few months later, I noticed I also needed to enable `--cap-add AUDIT_CONTROL` to get `sshd` to be able to do port forwarding.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 2):

You could also try forcing sshd to use ipv4. In your example, adding switch "-4" as follows:

```
ssh -4 -R 2024:localhost:22 -N remote.server
```

Answer (score 0):

following this steps helped me

- install `ssh` on the container
- enable the service with `/etc/init.d/ssh start`
- run `echo 'root:a-strong-password' | chpasswd`  to set password for root
- edit **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** and set `PermitRootLogin yes`
- then `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`
- then `ssh -fNTCR localhost:<YOUR-PORT>:localhost:22 remote-host` this goes to background and you can see it via `ps aux | grep ssh`
- then in **remote-host** we can login into it `ssh -p <YOUR-PORT> localhost`
- which asks for the **password** and you already created

screenhost

[image]

---

More info

1. [how-to-ssh-into-a-docker-container-remotely-as-root-or-a-non-root-user](https://medium.com/@leicao.me/how-to-ssh-into-a-docker-container-remotely-as-root-or-a-non-root-user-b2105c797273)